# iOS Voice Chat using Socket.io

Tags: android, ios, node.js, socket.io

I would like to implement a voice chat (even just a primitive support for it), without the hassle of implementing the whole VoIP stack. I would also like to make it available to both iOS and Android.

I have been searching for a way to do this, and it just seems to me that using [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) would be something to start with. Is it possible to use Socket.IO as a signalling server (to discover who is available, and who to start a voice chat with), and then establish a peer-to-peer connection between two devices in order to transfer audio data?

NOTE: Although I would prefer peer-to-peer, because I would like to avoid overloading the server with transferring such an enormous amount of data, is it possible to have socket.io receiving and transmitting audio data between devices (because I heard that iOS and Android cannot establish a P2P connection with one another). If it's not possible, then maybe it's possible to use a socket.io server as an intermediary for sending audio data?

I found the following helpful links (which are probably based on socket.io) but they have not any reference for mobile devices.

http://peerjs.com/

https://simplewebrtc.com/

Any help is greatly appreciated. Any alternatives to socket.io, are also accepted, if there are any.

Comment: I would like exactly the same... Should we join an create something for phones? It may be opensource... I would like to discuss more about P2P connection and socket.IO